# Benefits of @EnvironmentObject vs @ObservedObject with singleton in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

We can use an @EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI to hold an instance of an object available for multiple views:

```swift
class MyObject: @ObservableObject {
  var state = ""

  func doSomethingWithState() {
    //
  }
}
```

```swift
struct MyView {
  @EnvironmentObject var myObject: MyObject
}
```

However, we need to take care of this by adding .environment both to the main class and to every individual preview so that they don't crash:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
    var myObject = MyObject()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(myObject)
        }
    }
```

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
       MyView()
         .environmentObject(MyObject())
    }
}
```

In addition to that there is no easy way to access one environment object from another:

```swift
class MySecondClass: @ObservableObject {
  @EnvironmentObject MyObject myObject; // cannot do this 
}
```

I came across to a better solution using Singletons with static let shared:

```swift
class MyObject: @ObservableObject {
  static let shared = MyObject()
}
```

This was I can:

1. Use this object just like an @EnvironmentObject in any of my views:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
  @ObservedObject var myObject = MyObject.shared
}
```

2. I don't need to add any .environment(MyObject()) to any of my views because the declaration in 1. takes care of it all.
3. I can easily use any of my singleton objects from another singleton objects:

```swift
class MySecondObject: @ObservableObject {
  func doSomethingWithMyObject() {
    let myVar = MyObject.shared.state
  }
}
```

It seems to me better in every aspect. My question is: is there *any* advantage in using @EnvironmentObject over a Singleton as shown above?

Comment: For testing or previews you can inject a mock environment object, this is much harder with singletons

Comment: You are arguing that it’s inconvenient to having to declare environment objects and you can’t declare one inside another but be aware that having to many of them (or singletons for that matter) is bad code smell. They represent global state and if you have a lot of that your data and state management could become very difficult and testing will also be harder.

Comment: Singletons may seem convenient but are bad practice. You will end up in a code nightmare. It will be very hard to debug and very hard to grow.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: If I'm reading the comments above right then the advantage of @EnvironmentObjects is that they force us into decoupling code and prevent us from having a lot of singletons communicating between each other, which can lead to overcomplicated code?

Comment: singletons not good for multiple windows on iPadOS (and possibly macOS, I'm not sure about there) or multiple simultaneous instances of the view that need separate state.

Answer (score -2):

One way way is to set the environmentObject using a singleton.

```
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(MyObject.shared)
        }
    }
```

The reason is we must not init objects inside SwiftUI structs because these structs are recreated all the time so many objects being created is a memory leak.

The other advantage to this approach is you can use a different singleton for previews:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(MyObject.preview)
    }
}
```

FYI `@StateObject` are not init during previewing.